# unlisting and replacing empty elements as 0

Tags: r

I have a list with elements containing an integer or empty, e.g. `z <- list(10, 7, integer(0), 5, 4)`.

I want to convert it into an integer vector of the same length. Unlisting will remove empty elements, whereas I intend to pad those as 0.

At the moment what I've done is `sapply(z, function(x) {ifelse(length(x)==0, 0, x)})` . I'm curious if there's an existing R function or other approach that can perform this more elegantly?

Comment: That use of `ifelse` with length-1 arguments is kind of ugly. This is one instance where `if(){}else{}` would make sense and be more efficient. Furthermore, neither of them woul need the `==0` since they would both coerce arguments to logical and so `0==FALSE`.

Comment: I agree, that would be neater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `replace`

```
unlist(replace(z, !sapply(z, length),0))
#[1] 10  7  0  5  4
```

Or

```
 sapply(Map(`c`,z,0),`[`,1)
 #[1] 10  7  0  5  4
```

Or

```
 mapply(function(x,y) c(x,y)[1], z, 0)
 #[1] 10  7  0  5  4
```

Another option would be to assign the length to `1` (`length<-` ).  But, this gives `NA` for that particular element instead of `0`, which you can convert if needed.

```
sapply(z, `length<-`, 1)
#[1] 10  7 NA  5  4
```

by

```
 colSums(rbind(sapply(z, `length<-`,1),0), na.rm=TRUE)
 #[1] 10  7  0  5  4
```

Or if you need it in a list

```
ifelse(!sapply(z, length), 0, z)
```

Answer (score 1):

This forms a logical index which can be used be `"[<-"`:

```
 z[sapply(z, length)==0 ] <- 0
 z
#-------------
[[1]]
[1] 10

[[2]]
[1] 7

[[3]]
[1] 0

[[4]]
[1] 5

[[5]]
[1] 0
```

Technically I have satisfied your request because an R list qualifies as a vector. You might want to use `unlist` if the intent was to deliver an *atomic* vector, rather than a recursive vector.

Comment: ah sorry I wasn't explicit that I intend to have an atomic vector as the output.